# Removing a broken faucet aerator

Tags: repair, faucet, sink

The aerator on my bathroom faucet gets dirty, so I've been cleaning it out now and again by rubbing a paper towel around the bottom. I think I did this with too much force, because the plastic interior snapped right off.

Apparently you can unscrew an aerator and replace it, but this is my landlord's sink, so I just want to be sure what part to unscrew. I've attached images of the sink and the piece of the aerator that snapped off. Any ideas?

[image: Faucet]

[image: Piece that snapped off]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can unscrew and replace that aerator. Lucky for you, it appears to be a very common size and should be available at any hardware or plumbing shop (bring it with you).

The part you unscrew is the aerator body itself, the chrome part. Sometimes they are stubborn; you may have to get at it with pliers. I have even had to use destructive removal force on them on more than one occasion.

[image: Faucet piece to remove]